# How to use bind for all class files in current folder and sub-folder using HK2

Tags: java, dependency-injection, hk2

For doing dependency injection using HK2, In class that extends AbstractBinder, I need to write a lot of statements of type :

```
bind(Sample1.class).to(Sample1.class);
bind(Sample2.class).to(Sample2.class);
```

Example :

```
public class TestBinder extends AbstractBinder
{
   @override
   protected void configure()
   {
     bind(Sample1.class).to(Sample1.class);
     bind(Sample2.class).to(Sample2.class);
   }
}
```

Any short way of doing it without writing so much code (because there are 1000's of java classes in my folder)?

Comment: One way to clean up is to use `Feature`s. Group related services into a single Feature.. You can register the binder with the FeatureContext. Also, HK2 has [automatic service population](https://javaee.github.io/hk2/getting-started.html). You can use [this property](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/ServletProperties.html#SERVICE_LOCATOR) to pass in a parent locator.